Why don't the particles show up?
I'm new to unity, and would like to have particles appear at the point where the ray hits an enemy(hit.point). But this does not happen, and moreover, for some reason the bloodps variable “oscillates” between null and the prefab bound to it
public GameObject bloodps = null;

void Update()
{ 
    Debug.Log(bloodps);

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        { 
            Ray ray = _camera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit hit;

        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
            {
            GameObject hitObject = hit.transform.gameObject;
            EnemyCodeD enemy = hitObject.GetComponent<EnemyCodeD>();
            if (enemy != null) 
            {
                enemy.Hit();

                // Spawn particles
                if(bloodps != null)
                    Instantiate(bloodps, hit.point, new Quaternion(0, 0, 0, 0));


            }
```


It's not "oscillating". You have two ore more instances of this script in your scene, one that has had bloodps assigned correctly, and another that has not (or the object bloodps was pointing to got destroyed). new Quaternion(0, 0, 0, 0) is not a valid orientation - perhaps you meant to write Quaternion.identity instead?

You can try to set fields of your particle system: PlayOnAwake, Prewarm, Looping - to true. Can also create prefab from "bloodps " and drag the prefab to bloodps fields.
